# Keystone Error 404 "No Page could by found at this address (404)"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug, keystonejs

I'm running my keystone Website on localhost and I'm trying to create a new navigation link with a new site but I get an Error that the address behind the Link cannot be found.

The link is displayed in the navigation bar.

I created a file in /routes/views/aboutme.js with following code:

```
    var keystone = require('keystone');

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;

    // locals.section is used to set the currently selected
    // item in the header navigation.
    locals.section = 'aboutme';

    // Render the view
    view.render('aboutme');
};
```

And a .jade in /templates/views/aboutme.jade file with the code:

```
    extends ../layouts/default

block content
        h1 xyz
        p xyzxyzyxzxyzxyzyxzzxyz
        p xyzxyzyxzxyzxyzyxzzxyz
        p xyzxyzyxzxyzxyzyxzzxyz
```

Why the Page cannot be found? :/

Comment: Oh, wrong Code at the .jade , I'll be update this code later.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own.
For everyone, who has the same problem, in the /routes folder there is the index.js file.
In this code at the point:

```
    // Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {

}
```

Between the curly braces you have to write the following code:

```
app.get('/name', routes.views.name);
```

"Name" is your new sitename.